# How do I merge rows from a select statement based on conditions

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for the vague description, but I'm not sure how to say this.

Here is a sample result from a SELECT statement:

```
Number      Type      Name
67          NULL      George
67          Boy       Kevin
```

What I want:

```
Number      Type      Name
67          Boy       George
```

In other words, if Type is null I want to select the Name, but select the Type from the other row.

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT: I was asked in a comment to provide more information. The results above are simplified versions of the results from a much larger and more complex query. Here's a simplified version of that query to match. Also, I'm not asking for code. If I can get a pointer toward the solution, I can figure out the code myself. I'm just not sure which keywords I'm looking for. Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number, [Type], Name
FROM         MyTable 
WHERE     Number = 67
GROUP BY Number, [Type], Name
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I want to ask the best question possible. The results above are simplified from a much more complex SELECT statement I've written. I will supply a simplified version of that statement ASAP.

Comment: So the Number field is the connection between the two rows that says this is the Type value I want? Can there be multiple Type values per Number? If so, how do you pick which one? Etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one possible non-null Type value per Number, you can just do

```
SELECT 
    Number,
    ISNULL( Type, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Type FROM Table T1 WHERE T1.Number = T.Number) ) as Type,
    Name
FROM 
    Table T
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care *which* record is returned, if there's more than one non-NULL, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (ID INT, A VARCHAR(10), B VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Tbl (ID, A, B) VALUES
    (1, 'Alice', NULL),
    (1, NULL, 'Smith')

SELECT
    ID, MIN(A), MIN(B)
FROM
    @Tbl
GROUP BY
    ID
```

Output:

```
1  Alice  Smith
```